# when to use a cumulative timeseries?

Tags: mongodb

```
{
  timestamp: // date,
  metadata: // sensor_id,
  measure: // sales
}
```

Supposed that the above is a native timeseries collection in MongoDB.

Can it support a query that finds all documents between two timestamps and then computes some statistic, such as finding the sum, for the `measure` field on the documents in the range, if the range of documents will be in the millions?

If not, would a possible solution be to have a cumulative timeseries collection where each succeeding timestamp stores the cumulative sum of the `measure` field. So that for the query above, it would simply have to find the two documents matching the min and max of the timestamp range and then subtract the cumulative total?

Comment: There is no difference between a normal collection and a time series collection in terms of queries. The major difference of time series collection is the special type of index and the automatic deleting of old data

Comment: So would the special index enable the query to find the sum of a range of documents between 2 timestamps that may number in the millions?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries-collections/#behavior) is clear: "*Time series collections behave like normal collections. You can insert and query your data as you normally would*"

Comment: I am aware that it can be done. the question is it operation to find the sum of millions of documents any faster because it is a timeseries collection?

Comment: Ok, that's a different question. From the documentation I would assume it would be faster. I think you need to test it.